# How to use React Hooks to update different states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I am making a background component using [Vanta](https://vantajs.com) in NextJS, code below:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";
import FOG from "vanta/dist/vanta.fog.min";
import { useDarkMode, useWindowSize } from "./Hooks";

const updateColor = (darkMode) => {
    return {
        highlightColor: darkMode ? 0xff0000 : 0xffd2c6,
        midtoneColor: darkMode ? 0xbe1d1d : 0xff7737,
        lowlightColor: darkMode ? 0x781212 : 0x69c3ff,
        baseColor: darkMode ? 0x0 : 0xffffff,
    }
}

export default function Background({ children }) {
    const [vantaEffect, setVantaEffect] = useState();
    //returns the width and height of the window
    const windowSize = useWindowSize();
    //user presses a button to change the theme from light to dark
    const [mode] = useDarkMode();
    const vantaRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        const isDark = mode === "dark";

        if (vantaEffect) {
            setVantaEffect(
                vantaEffect.setOptions({
                    minHeight: windowSize.height,
                    minWidth: windowSize.width,
                    ...updateColor(isDark)
                }));

            vantaEffect.resize();
        } else {
            setVantaEffect(
                FOG({
                    THREE,
                    el: vantaRef.current,
                    blurFactor: 0.18,
                    minHeight: window.innerHeight,
                    minWidth: window.innerWidth,
                    ...updateColor(isDark)
                })
            )
        }

        return () => {
            if (vantaEffect) vantaEffect.destroy();
        }
    }, [mode, windowSize]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="fixed -z-50" ref={vantaRef}></div>
            <div>{children}</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Right now, if either mode or windowSize is updated, the canvas will both be resized, and re-rendered for dark mode. I want to be able to detect whether it was dark mode or the window being resized ran the useEffect function.

Additionally, whenever I try to lint the function, it asks me to add vantaEffect to dependencies. When I do, the effect renders too many times and lags the page.

Is there a better way to use hooks to render the background?

Comment: I have no idea what `vantaEffect` is, but the fact it is both a state variable, it has a function on it `setOptions` that looks like it should return a new `vantaEffect` object doesn't seem quite right.  You should store minimal data in state, not objects that contain functions that return new instances of themselves.  But the reason why you get constant rerenders, is that your condition around `if(vantaEffect){} else {}` will always call `setVantaEffect` so its an infinite loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split up the `mode` and `windowResize` you should use two separate `useEffect` hooks. By splitting them up these hooks will only execute when the dependency is updated.

What I noticed in your code is that you execute `vantaEffect.destroy()` on every render. I might be mistaken, but I think that is not what you want.
If you want to execute this code only on `unmount` you should add another `useEffect` without any dependencies in its array. (as stated in the React docs:

> When exactly does React clean up an effect? React performs the cleanup
> when the component unmounts. However, as we learned earlier, effects
> run for every render and not just once. This is why React ***also*** cleans
> up effects from the previous render before running the effects next
> time.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1)

The total would look something like this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const isDark = mode === "dark";

        if (vantaEffect) {
            setVantaEffect(
                vantaEffect.setOptions({
                    ...updateColor(isDark)
                }));

            vantaEffect.resize();
        } else {
            setVantaEffect(
                FOG({
                    THREE,
                    el: vantaRef.current,
                    blurFactor: 0.18,
                    minHeight: window.innerHeight,
                    minWidth: window.innerWidth,
                    ...updateColor(isDark)
                })
            )
        }
    }, [mode]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (vantaEffect) {
            setVantaEffect(
                vantaEffect.setOptions({
                    minHeight: windowSize.height,
                    minWidth: windowSize.width
                }));

            vantaEffect.resize();
        } else {
            setVantaEffect(
                FOG({
                    THREE,
                    el: vantaRef.current,
                    blurFactor: 0.18,
                    minHeight: window.innerHeight,
                    minWidth: window.innerWidth
                })
            )
        }
    }, [windowSize]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // only destroying the vantaEffect on unmount
        return () => vantaEffect?.destroy();
    }, []);
```

You should optimize the output, but I hope you get the idea

Comment: I see, I used to think that multiple useEffects was a bad thing, but I see it works really well, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to detect whether it was dark mode or the window
> being resized ran the useEffect function.

You can have two effects in your component one for `mode` and the other for `windowSize`.

> Additionally, whenever I try to lint the function, it asks me to add
> vantaEffect to dependencies. When I do, the effect renders too many
> times and lags the page.

You can use functional state update to access the previous state:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const isDark = mode === "dark";

    setVantaEffect((previousVantaEffect) => {
       // use `previousVantaEffect` and return what you want
    })

}, [mode])
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!